# setLayoutParams does not display things correctly

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, layoutparams

When I'm setting my layout parameters with xml, it works fine. But when I'm trying to set layout parameters programmatically, it works wrong. where did I failed?

I need to set parameters in my LinearLayout, here it is:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttons_layout"
        android:layout_width="231dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="85dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:baselineAligned="true"
        android:weightSum="603" >
```

And here is my code to set params:

```
rl = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.buttons_layout);
lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(pixelsFromDP(231), pixelsFromDP(40));
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
lp.setMargins(0, pixelsFromDP(40), pixelsFromDP(85), 0);
rl.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Here is what I'm getting by setting parameters by xml:
[image]

And here is what I'm getting by setting parameters programmatically:
[image]

method pixelsFromDP returns int value:

```
public int pixelsFromDP(int pixels){
        return (int)(40 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density + 0.5f);
    }
```

The reason of using this method is that in LayoutParams values are in pixels, but i need values in dp, so in this methos I'm converting dp into pixels depends on screen density

Oh shi, I found a mistake! OMG I'm so stupid :D

Probled solved by replacing "40" by  "pixels" in method pixelsFromDP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// Try this It work fine for me.  I thinks there is some problem in  pixelsFromDP()

```
    LinearLayout  rl = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.buttons_layout);
    LayoutParams    lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(231, 40);
      lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
      lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
      lp.setMargins(0, 40, 85, 0);
      rl.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
      rl.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Comment: can you share  pixelsFromDp() methods. I use int value as param then it work fine

Comment: pixelsFromDP() method returns int. Here it is:
public int pixelsFromDP(int pixels){
  return (int)(40 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density + 0.5f);
 }

Comment: The reason of using this method is that in LayoutParams values are in pixels, but i need values in dp, so in this methos I'm converting dp into pixels depends on screen density

Comment: public int pixelsFromDP(int pixels){ 
  return (int)(pixels * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density + 0.5f);
   
 }

Comment: use pixels instead of 40 in pixelsFromDP()

Answer (score 1):

I think LayoutParams are used in measuring phase, so when you do this programatically, you have to re-measure the layout, i would try to use invalidate(). I'm not 100% sure about this, but i think it's worth a shot.

Normally i would add this just as a comment, but as I don't have enough rep i have to post this as answer.

Comment: It didn't work.
By the way, my implementation worked some time ago, but suddenly stopped working without any huge changes in code. I only changed size of view (was like lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(pixelsFromDP(214), pixelsFromDP(37));)
That's all that I changed